# A few possibly duplicate questions about Java REST - what should we do?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

Please check out these links:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1710199/which-is-the-best-java-rest-api-restlet-or-jersey
- [REST in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66288/rest-in-java)
- [Java REST implementation: Jersey vs CXF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2704700/java-rest-implementation-jersey-vs-cxf)
- [Easiest frameworks to implement Java REST web services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1495813/easiest-frameworks-to-implement-java-rest-web-services)

I can't say that they are entirely duplicate of one another, but the difference is small. This information is too important to split between four different questions. What should we do? Which questions should be closed as duplicates?

Comment: ask for a question merge feature?

Comment: question merge feature would be awesome